ASP.NET Core 8 Cors headers not showing
I'm running into an unexpected issue getting Cors to run on an ASP.NET Core 8 Minimal API project. I setup a test project and just used the template to get it up and running then added what I thought should get the Cors stuff to show up but I'm not having any luck.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
const string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                "http://www.contoso.com");
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
    {
        var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
                new WeatherForecast
                (
                    DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                    Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
                ))
            .ToArray();
        return forecast;
    })
    .WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
    .WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary) {
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}

I then call this with: (edited based on feedback)
curl -vkX 'GET'   'https://localhost:8005/weatherforecast'   -H 'accept: application/json' -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"   -H "Origin: http://mysite.example.com"

and get this:
HTTP/2 200   
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
date: Sat, 27 Apr 2024 17:45:49 GMT  
server: Kestrel  
  
Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[
    { "date": "2024-04-28", "temperatureC": 25,"summary": "Balmy", "temperatureF": 76 },
    { "date": "2024-04-29", "temperatureC": 37,"summary": "Mild", "temperatureF": 98 },
    { "date": "2024-04-30", "temperatureC": 9,"summary": "Cool", "temperatureF": 48 },
    { "date": "2024-05-01", "temperatureC": 10,"summary": "Chilly", "temperatureF": 49 },
    { "date": "2024-05-02", "temperatureC": 17,"summary": "Mild", "temperatureF": 62 }
]

(I did edit out the handshake info)
I would expect to see the cors header(s) in the headers, but as you can see, it's not there. What am I missing?
Also not sure if this makes a difference, but I'm running from a Docker container.
Update/Solution
Make sure your origin sites match.  In my example above my origin is http://example.com but in my request header I have it set to http://mysite.example.com.  I over looked that. Sometimes it's the easiest issues that are hardest to see.

CORS stuff is relevant only to situations where request-initiator(user-agent) and web-server are based on different origins, right?

Aux question, what origin is curl user-agent based-on?

Try to setup different web-app, where one of the pages using simple button does requests to first weather app. Then checkout what happens in that case.

You need to explicitly allow request-header name Accept in your CORS policy; add a call to a .WithHeaders("Accept") on your builder. Also, you shouldn't expect to see CORS headers in a response to a request that lacks an Origin header; see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2f5e58c12084ec9bbe340377534bcf0a88fb36ed/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsMiddleware.cs#L107

Does this answer your question? How can you debug a CORS request with cURL?

@Ryan, I do have a React app that is accessing my API, this was just an attempt to boil down the question to the simplest parts.

@jub0bs your answer very helpful.  I've updated my curl request to try and trigger the cors but still not seeing any headers show up

@BryanBrown No surprise, though: http://mysite.example.com isn't listed as an allowed origin in your CORS configuration. Try again with an allowed origin. And don't forget to allow the Accept header. You should update your question to reflect the latest state of your (non-working) code. Also, see Ryan's answer; he might be on to something.

Setting up CORS policy name in actual middleware pipeline fixes the problem:
const string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
//..
//previous code omitted for brevity
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
//..
//following code omitted for brevity

Response headers:
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
    * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
    * old SSL session ID is stale, removing
    < HTTP/2 200 
    < content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    < date: Sun, 28 Apr 2024 12:47:36 GMT
    < server: Kestrel
    < access-control-allow-origin: http://example.com
    < 

I would recommend to always stick to official documentation, when introducing some tricky middleware.

Turns out my actual issue was I had https and the app I'm using is currently only doing http.

Try to add RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins)
app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
            new WeatherForecast
            (
                DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
            ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi()
.RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);


I've tried that.  It didn't change anything
